# How to fix Missing operating system after ms-sys

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I need your help. I've uninstalled ubuntu and removed his partition from Windows 7. After I restarted I had the "error: no such partition" so I used [this guide](http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/AmministrazioneSistema/RipristinoMbrWindows) to restore the windows bootloader...

Well, Windows is on /dev/sda1 (partition called C) but the guide tells:

"Do not specify the Windows partition, but only the disk containing the same, for example, /dev/sda and not /dev/sda1."

So I wrote on the terminal:

```
sudo ms-sys -w /dev/sda
```

And the terminal said me that the writing files are done succesfully. Now when I start my computer it says me:

Missing operating system

What the hell I did wrong?

---

EDIT:

Ops, I forgot to tell you that I have not any CD to restore windows because my computer is an Asus laptot (K53sv) and I have the recovery on another partition. When i press F9 during the start of my computer it happens nothing (before to install ubuntu I could restore windows with F9)...

Comment: Seems like a Windows question and this is an Ubuntu forum.  Do you have boot flag on sda1. Does sda1 have windows boot files? Does sda1 have correct partition boot sector which may require Windows tools to fix.

Comment: The problem was caused by Ubuntu and the only way to solve the problem is using Ubuntu... Anyway, I don't know and I can't know because windows doesn't start!

Comment: You need a Windows repair CD or flash drive to fix most Windows problems. But you can post the link to the summary report from this and it may tell what the issue is. It will not fix most Windows issues. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

```
Usage:
    ms-sys [options] [device]
Options:
    -1, --fat12     Write a FAT12 floppy boot record to device
    -2, --fat32nt   Write a FAT32 partition NT boot record to device
    -3, --fat32     Write a FAT32 partition DOS boot record to device
    -4, --fat32free Write a FAT32 partition FreeDOS boot record to device
    -5, --fat16free Write a FAT16 partition FreeDOS boot record to device
    -6, --fat16     Write a FAT16 partition DOS boot record to device
    -n, --ntfs      Write a NTFS partition Windows 7 boot record to device
    -l, --wipelabel Reset partition disk label in boot record
    -p, --partition Write partition info (hidden sectors, heads and drive id)
                    to boot record
    -H, --heads  Manually set number of heads if partition info is written
    -7, --mbr7      Write a Windows 7 MBR to device
    -i, --mbrvista  Write a Windows Vista MBR to device
    -m, --mbr       Write a Windows 2000/XP/2003 MBR to device
    -9, --mbr95b    Write a Windows 95B/98/98SE/ME MBR to device
    -d, --mbrdos    Write a DOS/Windows NT MBR to device
    -s, --mbrsyslinux    Write a syslinux MBR to device
    -t, --mbrgptsyslinux Write a syslinux GPT MBR to device
    -z, --mbrzero   Write an empty (zeroed) MBR to device
    -f, --force     Force writing of boot record
    -h, --help      Display this help and exit
    -v, --version   Show program version
    -w, --write     Write automatically selected boot record to device

    Default         Inspect current boot record
```

**-7, --mbr7      Write a Windows 7 MBR to device**

Test this:

```
sudo -i
ms-sys -7 /dev/sda
```